# Looking for a Synonym of "Movement" For a Game Attribute System

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm looking for a better word that better illustrates "movement", such as how "Jump" is better illustrated as "Acrobatics". *I'm already aware of the word "Athletics", but that seems more synonymous with general endurance and physical aptitude, instead of the act of simply moving/translating between point A to B.* I am using this for internal naming conventions for my game, which is a 3D turn based strategy game. Each actor you control is capable of jumping to higher positions via their "Acrobatics" score, a value between 0-12, and moving to new cells of the map based upon their "Movement" score, up to a maximum of 12 cells away.

Edit: To further lessen the gap of ambiguity, here is how the attribute system works in my game.

In my game, you control a group of four units, ranging in various classes (Or Birthrights as I call them), such as Paladin, Warrior, Ranger, Rogue, Priest, Arcanist, Bard, etc. These "actors" as I internally call them, each have their own individual "Grimoire". A Grimoire is like a [Sphere Grid](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Sphere_Grid) in Final Fantasy. You can place various "Glyphs" into the nodes of your Grimoire. Such glyphs are "Strength Glyph" "Agility Glyph" "Stamina Glyph", etc. This is how your characters grow and become stronger. My game does not have a level up mechanic. You gain Glyphs, and it's up to you how you develop your Grimoire(s). The Grimoire also has special Glyphs that you can find/purchase, like ones that increase the probablity of scoring a Critical Strike, or increasing your ability to Jump to higher ledges, or even move further during your turn. However, these Glyphs are more rare than casual Strength and Agility Glyphs; you can only use 12 maximum Movement/Acrobatics Glyphs per Grimoire.

My Primary Attribute System is located [here](https://pastebin.com/zDU7kAJw).

And the BattleAttribute System, which this question pertains to, is located [here](https://pastebin.com/nZMetBHa) (Still in development).

And the list of how my attributes work is located [here](https://pastebin.com/QQAwrwqL).

Here is an example of the word being used: ***"In this game you can increase your "movement" by gaining and spending "Movement Glyphs" in your actor's Grimoire."***

What is a more viable synonym for "Movement" in this scenario?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the asker rejected a suggestion because they “already have a datatype with that name”, so this request is not a question but rather is about choosing names for things in a program and choosing names for formal systems is specifically off-topic on ELU.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56857/discussion-on-question-by-krythic-looking-for-a-synonym-of-movement-for-a-game).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perhaps you are thinking of ***mobility*** or, more precisely, *locomobility*. From Oxford Dictionaries:

> [**mobility**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mobility) NOUN
>   *mass noun*
>   1. The ability to move or be moved freely and easily.

And more specifically to one's own intentional movement:

> [**locomobility**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/locomobility) NOUN
>   The ability to move from one place to another; a tendency to move about.

I'd prefer the latter for precision, but the former if you want to avoid any confusion with trains.

Comment: I do like Mobility, it could look good as a "Mobility Glyph" in the Grimoire.

Comment: Those are lovely words, but don't look like they work for a base stat representing distance traveled per turn in a game. Mobility is the *ability* to move/be moved (i.e., not being immobile), but isn't a synonym for speed.

Comment: @lly It's fine if you interpret the OP's request as being equivalent to *speed* (mathematically that makes sense), but the question on its face asks for synonyms for *movement*, and this is a *language* site, not a math site.

Comment: @Ily clearly I misunderstood what the OP was looking for.. I think this is a pretty good answer if the goal were differentiating movement from other activies. While your suggestion speed usually means movement it also might mean how many swings you could make per mele round, how quickly they react etc... but, of course it's a matter of opinion and style and feel.

Comment: @1006a It's fine if you don't want to read the question (although not sure how that makes sense) but *ability to not be immobile* and *rate of movement* are not synonyms and that has nothing to do with mathematics.

Comment: I actually like the word Mobility. I even plugged it into the code to see how it would look. Plus, "Mobility Glyph" looks better than "Speed Glyph"; it's less ambiguous upon first glance as to what it does/affects, too. Which would greatly help for people whom are playing my game for the first time.

Comment: I'm glad you like the suggestion. You might want to wait a little while to accept it, though, just because you might get more suggestions if you leave it open. If you wait about 24 hours, you will give all of the people around the world a chance to look at your question.

Comment: @1006a Alright, I removed the accept for now.

Comment: While I like "mobility" and voted it up, I do have one issue with it in a game. A "mobility glyph" could be expected to be more of a "free action" glyph that removed or made you immune to debuffs like web or slow spells.

Comment: @Tom22 Can you provide an alternative...one that isn't "Transit"?

Comment: I'm not against mobility or movement_speed . .. and I'm not against Speed either alone either Just brainstorming.. I don't know how far you expect to iterate on the game...whether you'll continue to add abilities or not. I'll let you know if I think of something else.  We enjoy Language here and brainstorming and seeing other answers is part of the fun.

Comment: @Tom22 I don't think I'm going to add any other attributes to the game. They all work pretty well together right now. Here is the mechanics of my attributes: https://pastebin.com/QQAwrwqL

Comment: I decided to just go ahead and choose you as the answer. I did end up using Mobility, because it's very clear as to what it will do, and sounds an awfully lot like a proper attribute name. Thank you for your time and suggestions.

Answer (score 7):

You're kidding, right?

A number that represents distance traveled in a set amount of time?

## Speed

Comment: Great suggestion! It should also be noted that Final Fantasy Tactics used a Speed attribute to denote the same thing.

Comment: @Krythic Not just FFT. Plenty of desktop RPGs that have a stat for speed separate from agility use 'speed'.

Comment: Would this quality also give extra buffs to attack rate ?.. You might want separate "movement speed" and "attack speed" glyphs.

Comment: @Tom22 There is no such thing as Attack Speed in my game. You get one turn per Actor you control, in which time they can perform one action, such as Move, Attack, or Use Item. Initiative, or the order of turns, is decided at the end of every turn. The player sets these values to whatever he/she wants, so next turn the actors will gain focus in the order that is desirable.

Comment: speed might work for you then if there isn't any attack speed to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

A 'transit' score would make clear the idea of going from the one place to the other. Even though it also can mean carrying things one place to another it would distinguish itself from stamina which might also refer to how much energy you have to jump or fight.

**Transit Points** or **Transit Ability** would seem to narrow itself to movement from A to B as you seemed to be looking for.  Anything that might encompass other activities like fighting or endurance wouldn't be isolated to from a to b movement.

!Other answers might be better if how ~fast~ is more important than how far, or if ability to ~move without impediment~ should be emphasized too.

***[transit](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/transit)***
[tran-sit, -zit]

> 1.
>   the act or fact of passing across or through; passage from one place to another.
>
> 2.
>   conveyance or transportation from one place to another, as of persons or goods, especially, local public transportation:

Comment: Did you even read my question? Does "transit" sound like it would suffice as a name of an attribute for a game?

Comment: yes .. like hit points or mana, the ability to move from one place to another would be transit ..

Comment: Sorry you don't like it.. the idea is suggestions and the transit points would clearly denote how much power you had to move. If it doesn't fit the "feel" that's one thing.. you don't need to accept it but I am a gamer and I would totally understand "transit points"

Comment: I removed my downvote on your suggestion. Still, I don't agree with it. I apologize for sounding harsh; I removed a comment that I should not have written.